# Change child form window title (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, forms, window, mdi

Can anyone enlighten me on how to change the window title of a child form in an MDI structure to the name of the file opened?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: VB6 or VB.NET? Who opens file, parent form or child form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marco says, it depends on your exact circumstances. However, this code (as copied from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkysca23%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) shows a simple example in both VB6 and VB.Net:

```
' Visual Basic 6.0
Dim F(1 To 4) As New Form1
Private Sub MDIForm_Load()
   Dim i As Integer
   Load Form1
   For i = 1 To 4
      F(i).Caption = "Form" & i + 1
      F(i).Show
   Next I
End Sub



' Visual Basic 2005
Private Sub MDIForm1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim i As Integer = 0
  For i = 0 To 4
      Dim F As New FormChild
      F.Text = "Form " & CStr(i + 1)
      F.Show()
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Uhm, so you think that when OP says _"the name of the file opened"_ he means the name of the form? Well, it's possible. Anyway, with the informations we have, your example is good. +1 for you.

Comment: @Marco: No, the samples were copied straight from that MSDN page with no changes what so ever. I assume he'll be able to figure out the names of the files he's just opened :)